# Webpack 2.1.0-beta.6 config file not picking up loaders for styling on windows

Tags: windows, less, webpack

I'm trying to get webpack 2.1.0-beta.6's style, css, less, and file loaders to catch on Windows Server 2008, Babel 6, and Node 4.3. If webpack has this loader configuration:

```
  loaders: [
    {
      test: /\.less$/,
      loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'less-loader']
    },
    {
      test: /.gif$/,
      loader: 'file'
    },

    {
      test: /\.js$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      query: {
        presets: ['es2015-native-modules']
      }
    }
```

The import `require('../styling/my-style.less')` fails with

> ERROR in ../styling/my-less.less Module parse failed:
>   .../my-style.less
>   Unexpected character '@' (1:0) You may need an appropriate loader to
>   handle this file type. | @import "other.css";
>   ./my-js.js 8:0-38

`require('style!css!less!../styling/my-style.less')` sort of works though. At least until it gets to a .gif file.

> ERROR in ../styling/themes/base/images/animated-overlay.gif Module
>   parse failed:
>   ..\styling\themes\base\images\animated-overlay.gif
>   Unexpected character ' ' (1:7) You may need an appropriate loader to
>   handle this file type. (Source code omitted for this binary file)  @
>   ./~/css-loader!./~/less-loader!../styling/my-style.less
>   10:46994-47046

My webpack config is in with my src directory and styles is a parallel directory

- src

  - webpack.config.js
  - my-js.js // file doing the import from styling
- styling

  - my-style.less

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of my loaders were getting picked up because under `module.exports`, I didn't have a `module` wrapping my loaders.

```
module.exports.loaders //doesn't work and require acts like there aren't loaders associated with the file type

module.exports.module.loaders //works
```